# Cavalieri's Method of Indivisibles

Tags: calculus

I have been asked to "attempt to show that $\int_0^a x^2 dx = \frac{x^3}{3}$ using Cavalieri's method of indivisibles". However, I have not been able to find any useful information about Cavalieri's method other than it is the ratio of the area of rectangular regions to the area of the enclosed rectangle. From http://www.math.wpi.edu/IQP/BVCalcHist/calc1.html. Any further insight into Cavalieri's method would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quadrature_of_the_Parabola for a solution without calculus.

Answer (score 0):

The "classical" solution is the one from Archimedes, who used abstract levers and indivisibles. The method shown on the Wikipedia page is the most famous one and was devised by Archimedes too, but it does use calculus (sum of an infinite series). The fact that it doesn't rely on "modern" calculus doesn't mean that it can be considered calculus-free.

For the mechanical proof, see [Matematicas Visuales](http://www.matematicasvisuales.com/english/html/history/archimedes/parabola.html) or [Wikipedia: The Method of Mechanical Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Method_of_Mechanical_Theorems#First_proposition_in_the_palimpsest). The Source of the proof is Archimedes's Palimpsest.